# Express JS Sessions across two subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, session, cors

I have express sessions across two subdomains it is setup as:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
const session = require('express-session');
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const domain = IN_PROD ? 'productiondomain.production' : 'testpage.test';
const sessionConfig = {
  name: 'sessions',
  secret: 'secret',
  store: new pgSession({
    pool: pool,
    tableName: 'session',
    pruneSessionInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    createTableIfMissing: true
  }),
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: {
    domain: `.${domain }`
    maxAge: 1 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60000,
    secure: IN_PROD,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'lax'
  }
}
app.use(session(sessionConfig));
const mainRouter = require("./routes/index.routes");
const apiRouter = require("./routes/api.routes");
app.use(vhost(`www.${domain}`, mainRouter));
app.use(vhost(`api.${domain}`, apiRouter));
```

The cookie sessions work when you are sending requests across the same subdomain eg. sending a post request from testpage.test to testpage.test/login will set the cookie. But if you send it from testpage.test to api.testpage.test/login it will create the session but won't save the cookie.

Similarly if you were on dashboard.testpage.test and tried to send a request to api.testpage.test and get the session variables it will just result in the session cookie being returned when using console.log(req.session):

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-03T10:29:39.479Z,
    originalMaxAge: 2592000000,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: '.testpage.test',
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'lax'
  }
}
```

Rather than including the variables like when sending a requesting a request from dashboard.testpage.test to dashboard.testpage.test like so:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-03T10:29:39.479Z,
    originalMaxAge: 2592000000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    domain: '.testpage.test',
    sameSite: 'lax'
  },
  email: 'user@email.com',
  user: 'user_id_here'
}
```

I've tried setting cors to origin: '*' but still no luck. Does anyone have any idea what's happening?